# Unable to Remove Local Notification from Lockscreen

Tags: ios, notifications, uilocalnotification, nsnotificationcenter, lockscreen

In my app, at some point I need to display some notification to the user, in case user didn't respond to them, I need to remove that notification. Now, if I call cancelAllLocalNotifications function it does remove notification from notification center (also removes the alert from Home-screen, when the device is unlocked).

But when device is locked and notification is displayed on the lock-screen. After sometime, my app calls **cancelAllLocalNotifications** function. Now, this **doesn't remove Notification from Lock-screen**, however there is no item in notification center.

Comment: Good question. I'm skeptical that there is actually a way to resolve this but my fingers are crossed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `cancelAllLocalNotifications` won't remove the already showed ones. It cancels all notifications that are scheduled. I don't think there is a way to clear a notification from the lock screen.

Comment: Yes you are right, I couldn't find any way to remove notifications from lock screen, thats sad.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it was not possible that time, but now you can cancel notification from the lockscreen. If anybody needs this now.

If you send a notification you have to store it somewhere to be able to identify it when it should be canceled.

All you have to do is

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(notification)
```

to identify the notification which should be canceled you can set information in the userinfo property

```
notification.userInfo = ["title": item.title, "UUID": item.UUID]
```